# Fatal Error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable To Load Template File

Tags: smarty, fatal-error, dashboard, prestashop-1.6, uncaught-exception

my back-office (dashboard/administrator) wouldn't show anything but a blank white page. After i switched on debug mode I got the following explanation:

Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file 'helpers/form/form.tpl' <-- thrown in E:\HostingSpaces\User\mywebsite.com\wwwroot\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 129

I've tried to upload newer "fresh" versions of prestashop and to delete the database and bring it back with backups nothing worked. I changed the rights for the whole tools folder, and I have deleted al content of directories /cache/smarty/cache/ except the file index.php and cache/smarty/compile/ also except file index.php.

But nothing helped this morning everything was working until I tried to switch the sub-domain to the main domain for updates.

I'm currently working with Prestashop version: 1.6.1.4

Strangely enough both of the websites have the front-desk working without any problem.

*Obviously i've changed the details in the error message to general info for privacy reasons.

Can anyone please help me with this!!!!!!

PS: I by now have changed the right to each and every folder plus files to 777. And that didn't change a thing.
Although I must add that my ftp program (filezilla) gave me this answer several times:  504 Command not implemented for that parameter

Comment: does this file exist in your system ? `E:\HostingSpaces\User\mywebsite.com\wwwroot\admin\themes\default\template\helpers\form\form.tpl`

Comment: Florian! thanks! the whole folder helpers was missing! Nobodies knows why, but somehow my ftp and server didn't agree on me loading it or something. Now force fed this folder to the server and it worked. Everything is available again! Thanks for the tip to the right path.....

Comment: How do I set the query as "solved"?

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept my answer below to mark this question as solved. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file is missing from your system:

```
E:\HostingSpaces\User\mywebsite.com\wwwroot\admin\themes\default\template\helpe‌​rs\form\form.tpl
```